# Repeated Calls to handleMessage() hanging the device

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

If i made single call to `handleMessage()` from a thread it works just fine. but if i made more than one call to `handleMessage()` say for example if i wanna use it inside `loop` it doesn't work it hanging out

why it happens?

this inside the thread

```
Message msg = Message.obtain();
        msg.obj = "My message!";

            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```

hint : i wanna call the `handleMessage()` many times inside loop to update the progress bar but i can't call it more than one time?

Comment: you could send message multiple time instead of `handleMessage()` . You shouldn't call `handleMessage()` by yourself .. just send message mutiple time but everytime don't forget to change the msg object to use `Message.obtain()` everytime